# How to store an AES password in a SQLite database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, aes

I am trying to store a password in a SQLite database using this code:

```
public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
    return encryptedValue;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
    return key;
}
```

and this byte array as key

```
private static final byte[] keyValue = 
        new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
            'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };
```

but the problem is where to store that key, because using that key, anybody can decrypt the data and cause security issues..

Please help me....Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a user generated key like a pin screen. You will not need to store it when the app starts ask the key to the user, and then keep it in memory until the app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

No matter where you place your secret key. If I can decompile and run your code only thing I have to do is just place breakpoint just a line after key is created. There is no working method to place encrypted data in your code and make it available only for your code.